# Does the publisher of a book indicate much about reliability?

Tags: discussion, references

Are certain publishers of books more reliable than other publishers?

For example, if a book is published by Routledge, like the first book cited in [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/20140/104), is that a useful indicator that the book is an honest, scholarly attempt at history?

(For what it's worth, [here's](http://intersections.anu.edu.au/issue9/morris_review.html) a review of the book. Not universally bad, not universally good.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think some publishers are more reliable than other publishers. Knowing the reliable from the unreliable is one part of being an expert in a particular field.

The expert who has come to know one publisher as less reliable only uses this as a clue that they should be looking for extra sources to confirm what they've read.

This knowledge is what makes domain experts more efficient at finding the best evidence for a particular question.